# ASP Classic Website Usage Metrics

Tags: iis-6, asp-classic, metrics

We have a ASP Classic Web site Running on IIS 6.  What is the cleanest way to record the number concurrent users?  We need this data over a period of time, and a way to sum it across servers would be great.  What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Services object in Performance Monitor has counters for number of current connections (and some others that might be useful - current anonymous users, current nonanonymous users, anonymous users/sec, etc.). You could setup the counters, then pull the data from each server into Excel to combine and analyze.

Comment: I take it that Web Services in this case doesn't refer to SOAP?

Comment: No, nothing to do with SOAP/etc. It is just the name in perfmon for (some of) the IIS related counters.